# Does a, “5% oil life remaining” dash message mean low quality or low quantity, or both?

Tags: engine, oil, oil-change, fluid-level

I’ve never seen this question answered on any boards. When my 2008 Ford Escape says I have 3% oil life remaining, I know it means I’m due to change it. But for curiosity sake, is the algorithm or actual gauge testing for volume and/or quality? I think that’s as straightforward as I can ask.

I’d much rather drive with enough low quality oil than none at all!

Thanks.

Comment: You can research it yourself. Check the oil level on the dipstick. If it is low, top it and see what the indicator says.

Answer (score 13):

Realistically, it doesn't mean either.

The life expectancy is just that, how long you should be able to continue to use the oil which is in there. There is nothing wrong with the oil. It will continue to perform as it is supposed to. Your engine can use it in good health. At 3% your oil is getting close to needing it changed. The oil will continue to function as it should, even after it reaches 0%. It will continue to lubricate, cool, reduce friction, etc., it just won't do it as well as fresh oil does. It will continue to degrade and become the oil you're talking about. The algorithm isn't perfect, though. It is an indicator. You can bet the manufacturer/engineers err on the side of caution with this, because if the engine fails due to poor oil health while under warranty, they'd be replacing the engine at no cost to the owner.

Secondarily, it is not low on oil. Most engines today have an oil level sensor which indicates if your oil is too low. A dash light will usually come on telling you the oil is low. Conversely, you can pull the dipstick and see the level as well if there's not a dash light (probably the preferred method).

Answer (score 6):

Most "Oil Minder" or oil condition monitoring programs are similar in function. The program monitors the way you drive. It tracks if you do lots of long distance high speed driving or lots of short cycles where the engine doesn't reach operating temperature or a combination of types. Some also measure the electrical conductivity of the oil. It uses the data to determine when the oil needs to be changed. It is more accurate than the strictly mileage method. My personal experience with General Motors system proves it works. I have a short commute where the engine only reaches full operating temp for my last 1/4 mile. In the winter when the engine may not even reach the point where I have heat the change interval may be as low a 2000 miles. While in the summer it might be as high as 4000 miles. An important point of these systems is that they must be reset when the oil is changed. The method to reset varies by manufacturer. The percent of oil life remaining is just an indicator of relative amount of time before the oil needs service. It is also a means for the dealer to deny a warranty claim based on you driving it for 10000 miles after the indicator came on.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably just a message hooked into the odometer to remind you to change the oil every n thousand miles.

There is really no substitute for checking your oil the old fashioned way, in my opinion.  Computers can't account for all driving conditions, what kind of oil you may have put in there, the age of the engine, and other factors.

On older engines where you get more blow-by gases getting gas into the crankcase, you can smell the gas in the oil.  I always smell the dipstick when checking my oil. The oil can thin out and lose its lubricity before turning very dark.

I use a white paper towel and examine the oil when I wipe the dipstick.  If it looks really dark, is too thin, or smells like gas, it's time to change it.

Synthetic oil is definitely better than regular.  It has consistent molecule size, better temperature stability and performance at temperature extremes, and lasts longer.  3000 miles is a good estimate for older cars. Newer ones can go longer, maybe 5-10 but it really depends. Again, there's no substitute for checking it yourself.

Mobil 1 full synthetic and zmax additive have kept my civic running smoothly > 210k miles on the same engine.

Comment: Just a quick note for the benefit of future readers that "looks really dark" is the normal condition of oil in diesel engines, and unlike in petrol engines doesn't mean an oil change is needed.

Comment: Also, oil life indicators are hooked into more than just the mileage (or odometer). The computer can tell the load put on the engine, as well as a lot of other factors, and uses these to compute the amount of life the oil should have left in it. The engineers who designed the vehicles came up with this and it should be a fairly good indicator of what life is left on the oil. As per your ideas on what a "good estimate" is, really it's just conjecture. If you have any reliable sources for what you're saying, I'd highly suggest you add links to your answer.

Comment: I agree 100% ...snip... Your recommended oil change interval (in miles or kilometers) can be found in your owners manual. If the manual calls for conventional oil you may be able to change your oil less often with good quality synthetic oil. Especially if you drive mostly longer trips on the highway. The best way to see how accurate the "change your oil" light is Is to send your old oil off to get tested after you change it. There's a few companies that do this. You mail it to them and they mail you back a paper telling you what th

Answer (score 0):

It means neither of those things that you mention.
It means you need to change your oil.
It also means that the alogarithm used to determine the life of the oil in your engine is at a point where it will NOT function as necesarry to prevent damage to your engine.
This, of course is dependent on whether the oil that is in your engine meets the specifications set forth by the factory. If you somehow used an inferior oil, your engine is on borrowed time.
If this is a GM vehicle, the computer used to "work" the "oil life monitor" is much more than just a simple mileage counter or hour meter, it uses many factors to determine that the oil is at the end of its useful life.